# LUA: How can extract specific values from a xls or csv file and save them as variables?

Tags: excel, search, lua

I'm a beginner in lua (at best).

I have a *.lua script that at some point has a function that when called sets a set of variables. (or updates them)
These specific variables should be extracted from a xls or csv file - something that can be managed by excel.

So in excel I have rows and columns like this:

valuefield_1   100   20  30

valuefield_2   60   150  40

valuefield_3   80   90  170

etc.

I want to be able to search for a specific valuefield through lua in xls/csv, for example "valuefield_1" and get the value in the third third column, which would be 20. This is then saved as variable x in my lua script so that whenever I call variable x, it uses the value 20 until I update variable x with a different value by searching for a different valuefield value.

In my efforts to find a solution to this (seemingly simply) issue, all I came across are xls modules for lua, how to output files, how to do graphs, complicated stuff far beyond what I want to do.

Isn't there a simple way that I can have a line where it defines my variable by saying:

variable_x = value of the cell in the third column in the row of valuefield_x

so that I can simply set valuefield_x in my luascript according to what sort of valuefield I look for?

That's really all I need, I don't need to write xls/csv files or change anything in them. All I want is to accurately read specific cells in specific columns that are chosen by what "valuefield" I search for in the first column.

Can somebody tell me what the commands for that are?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer, Schollii.
The problem was pretty much that I didn't even know how to begin with accessing, opening, editing or otherwise using Excel through lua, so any code example was pretty much useless. Thus I thought it best to describe what I required, rather than misdirecting with code snippets that dealt with entirely different things. (such as io.open and other things)

As always, after much - MUCH - research and browsing through 3 different manuals and rereading who knows how many irrelevant answers I came upon an answer that works for me. It's actually very simple, so I cannot begin to imagine how many people could've spared me the hours and hours of research with a five minutes answer. Let's hope that by providing a very thorough answer, I can ensure that other beginner like me who wish to do the same don't have to do the same amount of research. And yes, the answer is very basic, and yes, I'm also explaining things most people who know lua code don't need explained. This is for beginners like me.

**First:** Download "Lua for Windows"
http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/

Lua cannot - by itself - handle excel format, so instead you need to use the plugin LUACOM which is one of the modules installed through "Lua for Windows"
It also includes a nifty script editor whith which you can right-click your scriptfile, click edit script, and you have a nice interface to edit and TEST your script.

**The actual script:**

The first part of your script requires you to utilize Excel through luacom.

```
require('luacom')
excel = luacom.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = true
```

a.The "require" line tells lua that it requires the module "luacom", to use the modules function for this lua script.

b. The second line through luacom opens an instance of Excel which is in the script referred to as "excel". This is necessary be able to target it with commands.

c. excel.Visible determines whether the open instance of excel can be seen by the user or whether its used invisible. Note how the "excel." reference points at the instance we called "excel" in line 2.

(Alternative)
It's also possible to target an existing instance of excel that has already been opened manually by the user by replacing the second line with:

```
excel = luacom.GetObject("Excel.Application")
```

If we use the alternative way, and target an already open excel program, we can already target all the values in the first sheet. If we however create a new instance of excel, we have to open the file we wish to read from.

```
fpath = "C:\\Examplepath\\Example.xlsx"
wb = excel.Workbooks:Open(fpath)
ws = wb.Worksheets("ImportantSheet1")
```

a. In the first line of this part, fpath determines the location of the xlsx file we wish to access. Note that "\" are used instead of "\".

b. We create the reference "wb" similar to the "excel reference in our first part of code. This one however opens a Workbook file (your excel file) at the location (fapth). Again, note how "excel." points the code at the excel instance we created earlier.

c. This line determines which sheet is to be opened in the just opened Workbook file. In this case, it's the sheet called "ImportantSheet1".

```
desired_name = "whatIseek"
for row=1, 4 do
    for col=1, 4 do
        local cell_location = excel.Cells(row, col).Value2

        if cell_location == desired_name then
            Value1 = excel.Cells(row, col +1).Value2
            Value2 = excel.Cells(row, col +2).Value2
            Value3 = excel.Cells(row, col +3).Value2
        end
    end
end

            print(Value1)
            print(Value2)
            print(Value3)
```

a. desired_name sets up the value that we seek (in this case a string)

b. Line 2 and 3 determine that the following process is to be done for rows 1-4 and columns 1-4, though you don't have to call those "row" or "col".

c. The next line sets the value of the variable "current cell" to the value of the cell in excel at the position (x, y). You *need* to use ".Value2" (not ".Value") to in this command. So now our temporary variable has the cells value.

d. In the "if" command, we check if the current value of the cell is equal to the value we specified earlier as the "desired_name" which we seek.

e. If that is the case, "then" the next 3 lines set the Values 1-3 to the cells in the next columns in the same row. (So it "reads" from left to right the next values and saves them as our variable)

f. Finally, to check whether we actually have the values we want, we use the print command to view them when we execute the script. (This is, of course, not necessary to work with those values, this is merely here to check if this script works)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a .xls file reader in Lua and in doubt writing one in pure Lua is feasible (although look at [xlrd module in Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd), might be easy to convert to Lua). In Python you can do that easily with win32com module so if you have option of using Python instead it is very easy to learn.

For .CSV file you would use open and read just as any other text file then parse with Lua pattern matching. If you post some where you show what you have tried (that's probably why you got so many downvotes) with these then I can post more specific answer.